# How to deal with the current going opposite direction through battery

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, voltage, batteries

Say that the current source is doing whatever it needs to do to output $1$A and that the battery is a $3$V battery. For simplicity, say the resistor is $1\Omega$.

[image]

I get that since we have $1$A through the resistor, the drop has to be $1$V. I don't how to find the potential difference between some point before the battery and the rightmost ground.

Does the direction of the battery matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the diagram, it is shown that $i = 1$A is flowing into the positive terminal of the battery.

There is a $-3$V potential difference across the battery because the (positive) charge is losing 3 volts when flowing across the battery because it's flowing into the positive terminal and out of the negative terminal. There is an additional $x$ dropped because of the internal resistor. Using Ohm's law on the resistor $x = iR$, we find that $x = 1$V so in total there is a potential difference of $4$V.

In short, the battery is the opposite way than it usually is. This is what some would consider a trick question.

**Explanation without discussing charge sign:**

In the most traditional circuit, [image]

current flows out of the positive terminal into the negative terminal. That is, it flows from the long bar to the short bar, so clockwise here.  This means that when the current goes across the battery, it gains a voltage. In the example of OP's, the current is flowing the opposite way, so the battery is making the current lose voltage.

Comment: how do you know the charge is positive, if the charge was negative wouldn't it be gaining 3V.

Comment: This probably sounds really dumb, but how does the charge gain pd? Isn't the purpose of a battery to provide pd. Why is this circuit based of conventional current, rather than electron current?

Comment: Thank you so much for taking your time to help me understand this question and just electricity in general. So just to be clear, in most electricity questions, do we always assume that convential current is being shown?

Comment: The direction of current is given by  Kirchhoff's laws so we actually never assume the direction, we can find what it is. For the circuit that I posted, the current is always going to be clockwise because it generally flows from positive to negative on the terminals but for more complicated circuits with more than 1 battery sometimes its unclear which way it flows. Then we need the Kirchoff's laws. Also, I am glad I could help. Also, Id appreciate if you mark the question as completed.

Comment: sorry again, but why did you assume that the current is moving in the conventional traditional way, why can't it be an electron current. Sorry but I am actually so confused right now, I posted the question on chegg (which I don't really know the reliability of) and it did the same steps as I did so also got 2V, but my teacher says it's 4V. Why can't the answer be 2V?

Comment: In the picture, the current has an arrow that shows its direction. The picture is saying the current is flowing into the negative terminal. This alone is enough to conclude its losing the 3V. Forget about the eletrons for this, just think about the direction of the current.

Comment: ohh I see, thank you very much